# Octave error: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib

Tags: octave, x11

When I try to open Octave, I get the following error:

```
$ exec '/Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/octave'
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/octave-3.4.0
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/octave: line 68: 60135 Trace/BPT trap: 5       OCTAVE_HOME="${OCTAVE_HOME}" PATH="${PATH}" DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}" CC="${CC}" CXX="${CXX}" CFLAGS="${CFLAGS}" CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS}" CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS}" FFLAGS="${FFLAGS}" LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}" DL_LDFLAGS="${DL_LDFLAGS}" SED="$SED" MAGICK_HOME="${ROOT}" FONTCONFIG_PATH="${ROOT}/etc/fonts" "${ROOT}/bin/octave-3.4.0" "$@"

[Process completed]
```

I don't know whether it was caused by when I upgraded from OSX 10.9 to 10.10, reinstalled XCode, or replaced rvm with rbenv (I've done all three within the past 24 hours).  Reinstalling Octave (installed via and gnuplot (installed via brew) does not fix this issue.  How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling X11 (XQuartz) fixed this issue.